# News Article with structured data

Tags: structured-data

I'm trying to create structured data for a newspaper.

Some articles don't have an image.

Shall I just remove the image from the json-ld or put it in without a value? (Google complains in  both cases).

Are articles without images a different type of NewsArticle?

Comment: how about an array variable called media?

Comment: I don't understand - there's no media whatsoever in the article. So the question is, how to handle this case.